# Prime factors in c by using only recursion

Tags: c

I wrote this program in C for prime factors but its crashing after printing first prime factor, So i need help

```
#include<stdio.h>
void prime(int n,int i)
{
    i=2;
    if(n%i==0)
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
        n=n/i;
        prime(n,i);
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
        prime(n,i);
    }
}
void main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    prime(n,2);
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger?

Comment: No @ArndtJonasson , I dont know how to use that

Comment: Then you should learn, because they are useful.

Comment: Note that `prime` *always* calls itself, violating the Prime Directive of Recursion.

Comment: Do a google search in how to debug a program. Also, first thing in your prime function sets a parameter to a fixed value? Whats the point of passing the parameter then?

Comment: Where is the recursion terminal case. ie. When will `prime` ever return?

Comment: I was confused in returning so i  used printf instead of return

Comment: You always overwrite the `i` argument passed.

Comment: okay @WeatherVane now all prime factors are getting printed but its still crashing after printing all prime factors

Comment: And now your program looks like what?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson i removed i=2 and everything else is same

Comment: Then all the comments that were not about i=2 still apply, don't they? If you use the algorithm by hand, you stop at some point, or you would continue all your life. So when should the program stop?

Comment: yes but i dont know what should be return @ArndtJonasson

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void prime(int n,int i)
{
    if(n==0)
        ;
    if(n==1)
        ;
    else if(n%i==0){
        printf("%d ", i);
        n=n/i;
        prime(n,i);
    }
    else{
        i++;
        prime(n,i);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    prime(n,2);

    return 0;
}
```

If you add the cases for `n==0` and `n==1` (and remove the `i=2;`), you'll be all set.

---

edit - removed voided main as suggested by Jonathan Leffler

Comment: Now that the program more or less works, it's time to point out that recursion is not a good substitute for loops in C. Try for example the number 3167361. I don't know its factors, but it overruns the stack for me.

Comment: And it's also not really very efficient: it tries all composite `i` although their factors have already been divided away. But as a first try, it's a good program.

Comment: The factors of that are: 1, 3, 9, 351929, 1055787, 3167361

Comment: The prime 351929 alone is sufficient to exhibit the problem.

Comment: Thank You @ArndtJonasson

Comment: Note that 9 is not a prime factor (and neither is 1): the prime factors of 3167361 are 3, 3 and 351929.

Comment: I listed all the factors @JonathanLeffler , not prime factors. But yes, you are correct

Comment: See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for a discussion of why `void main()` is dubious — supported only on Windows.  I realize you probably just copied the code from the question, but …

Comment: @AlindKumar you might be interested in this [Prime Factors Calculator](http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/primefactorscalculator.htm) to check your work.

Answer (score 1):

It's doing an infinite loop as you are resetting `i` every time when doing

```
i = 2;
```

But even without that, you'll probably overflow `i` and you don't have a recursion terminal case.

you will have to rethink your logic for this to work.

Comment: okay now all prime factors are getting printed but its still crashing after printing all prime factors

Comment: Can u give me a hint

Comment: I'm sorry but you should really try to do this yourself.
[SO rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)